# Encrypt/Compress a 17 digit number to a smalller 9(or less) digit number.

Tags: information-theory

I have a unsigned long integer(8 bytes) which is guaranteed to be of 17 digits and i want it to store in int(4 bytes) which is of 9 digits at max. Basically i want to encrypt or compress the number so that i could retrieve the number without any loss of information.

Comment: How can you store more information in less space without loss of information ?

Comment: Do you mean your integer will be at least $10^{17}$ (or $2^{17}$)?

Comment: Is there anything interesting about the unsigned long integer you have?

Comment: I guess in theory you could convert to hexadecimal to reduce the length, but even so you can't get $9$ digits since $10^{17}>16^9$

Also: this may depend on the number. It may be that you can produce the number using less information than the number itself (for example if the number has an easy prime decomposition)

Comment: Even limiting it to numbers greater than $10^{17}$ doesn't help as there are still lots of values larger.

Comment: @IanMiller  integer would be of 10^17 not 2^17

Comment: @Element118 No it was just to show the motive that i want the same number to be stored in lesser space i.e. int

Answer (score 4):

There are $9 \times 10^{16}$ different decimal integers with $17$ decimal digits.

There are $2^{4\times 8} \lt 4.3 \times 10^9$  possible values of four bytes, a much smaller cardinality.

So you cannot find a $1-1$ injection from the former set to the latter.